# Uninstalling a magento extension

Tags: wordpress, magento

I've been trying to uninstall a magento plugin I've recently installed to reinstall it using Magento Connect. The log said that the plugin uninstalled successfully and if I go to the admin panel, the plugin's no longer there but when I went back to Magento Connect, the plugin is still listed there so I can't reinstall. Why is this happening?

Based on the answers, what I've tried so far are:

- Clear cache through Admin Panel
- Removed wordpress entry in core_resource
- I've made sure wordpress xml in etc/modules is removed
- I've made sure Fishpig folder in app/code/community is removed
- Cleared cache in var/cache
- Cleared cache in downloader/cache
- Checked if there's xml for wordpress in var/package (there was none)
- Reindexed magento

And none of this worked. The wordpress extension was still listed as installed in Magento Connect. I've been trying to uninstall repeatedly but it just won't go away even though the log said that the uninstall process completed. I've also tried reinstalling and upgrading. No success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for all your help and time. I really appreciate it. I've managed to solve the problem. It's apparently a problem with permissions. I didn't realize soon enough that the permission for all folders had to be 777. I had most folders set to 777 except for 2 files on my etc folder (local and locals.xml) because of security issues. But after getting a go signal changing said permissions, I managed to uninstall the plugin and reinstall it. Now the Wordpress is fully integrated in the website with no problems and I've also returned the permissions for local and locals.xml back to it's original. Thanks again a lot for all your time.

Answer (score 1):

to remove the extension:

remove all the modules files, includeing the file which enables the module:

```
app/etc/modules/COMPANY_MODULE.xml
```

also make sure the entry is gone from the database by removing the correct entry in table:

```
core_resource
```

then refresh the magento cache

It should then disappear from connect.

Comment: All the corresponding files in the Magento folder is already gone. I've also already removed the wordpress entry in core_resource table.

Answer (score 1):

Which module have you installed? Can you give me name so I can give you solution if possible for me. If module add new own tables in db then dont delete any module file otherwise may be magento crash. Its better way to uninstall from magento connect manages.

Comment: If still module is listed after uninstall it, please check all module files are removed from  your magento i.e app/... if not then delete it manually.Module is listed because of only this reason.

Comment: Well I've already checked, there are no more there's no more fishpig folder in app/code/community. And wordpress.xml is no longer in modules folder. so i'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Clear the .cache folder in the downloader directory, in addition there is also another area where an xml can be present in var/package/

The package files are from magento connect so delete from here and have another check!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it didn't work either. The plugin is still there.

Answer (score 1):

delete all files in var/cache/ and double check you are actually working in the right folder!  if you have another caching system then clear it.

Comment: I'm 200% sure that I'm working on the right folder. I've tried what you suggested and it's still there.

Comment: is the module still in use in the system or just in the connect system?

Comment: That I'm not 100% sure but I think only in Magento Connect. The module isn't even on the list of modules in the admin panel anymore. But if I go to Magento Connect, the plugin is still listed and when I try to install, the system says that the plugin is already installed.

Answer (score 1):

To delete the extension from Magento Connect (I believe you have already uninstalled it from Magento) you will need to delete the file var/package/Fishpig_Wordpress_Integration_{{version}}.xml